# Untracked files in vendor stay untracked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I made changes to my Rails app and added and committed them thru Git. However, I have two files that stay untracked whatever command I use. I tried `git reset --hard HEAD` and `git clean -f` but they don't have any effect. I'm now wondering what to do. Can I just make a pull request and merge with master?

```
On branch design-testimonial-page
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)

    modified:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-f79e470a04d3 (modified content)
    modified:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bundler/gems/inherited_resources-652686148f55 (modified content)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

When I did `git diff` I got the following:

```
diff --git a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-f79e470a04d3 b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bundler/gems/acti
--- a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-f79e470a04d3
+++ b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-f79e470a04d3
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Subproject commit f79e470a04d3ef25230803d83a6b1d26ad5c171a
+Subproject commit f79e470a04d3ef25230803d83a6b1d26ad5c171a-dirty
diff --git a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bundler/gems/inherited_resources-652686148f55 b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bundler/g
--- a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bundler/gems/inherited_resources-652686148f55
+++ b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bundler/gems/inherited_resources-652686148f55
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Subproject commit 652686148f554fb9ce0ebee5d857b3d3decc0272
+Subproject commit 652686148f554fb9ce0ebee5d857b3d3decc0272-dirty
```

Comment: What's your Git version? `git version`
Also, can you show me your `git add .` screenshot?

Comment: `git add .` shows me nothing. It just jumps into new line. Git version is `git version 2.15.0`.

Answer (score 0):

These are not *untracked files*.  Things that are in the:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
```

section are, by definition, *tracked*.  The word *tracked* just means *in the index*, with the word *index* defined as in the [gitglossary](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html).  (It is also called the *staging area* or sometimes the *cache*.)

In this particular case, the parenthesized bit:

```
... (modified content)
```

tells us that these are not *files* either.  Most index entries are for files, but Git supports what it calls *submodules* (see [the `git submodule` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-submodule.html)), which are references in one Git repository telling Git that it should clone and use some other Git repository, at some specific commit.

Here, there two other repositories, located in the directories:

```
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-f79e470a04d3
```

and:

```
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bundler/gems/inherited_resources-652686148f55
```

Each of these two Git repositories does not match its particular checked-out version.  Your `git status` is configured to descend into each submodule and query and then summarize that submodule's status, so your Git goes into the first one and finds that it has uncommitted changes, then goes into the second one and finds the same thing.

Note that if you go into these repositories yourself, you'll get more detailed information about what is changed within them.  If you then add and commit those changes, you'll get a *new* commit *for the submodule*.  If you want the superproject to use that new commit, you must then navigate back to the superproject and update *its* index / staging-area so that it records the new commit hash ID.

If you did not mean to modify the submodules, you can go into them and clean them up.

Comment: So I see in the git submodule documentation a number of options. I don't know exactly which one to take. I suppose I need to do `git submodule add` but then I'm no sure what to put behind it. Could you help me with this?

Comment: Someone else must have already added each dependency as a submodule, or you wouldn't have it (that submodule-dependency) now. So, once you've committed your fixes to/in the submodule (and, presumably, delivered that commit / those commits to the submodule's owner so that they can publish it widely), you'd `git add` the submodule back to the superproject. But those names—`gems/<name>-<hash>`—suggest that perhaps, whoever designed the superproject is assuming that the submodules won't ever change, and should be kept on those hash IDs forever. I don't know what the designer intended here.

Comment: Well in the end I went to folder of these repositories and deleted them and then added and commited the deletion of the files. Afterwards they didn't come back Git anymore. So that solved my problem.